# Automount NTFS partitions in Linuxmint 14 KDE

Tags: ntfs, linux-mint, kde, fstab, automount

I am trying to set an NTFS partition to be auto-mounted in Linuxmint 14 **KDE**. I have already added command in `/etc/fstab` file as below:

`/dev/sda1 /media/MyDrive ntfs defaults 0 0`

After saving the file when I tried to mount it myself, by clicking on the drive name on left panel in Dolphin file browser, it shows errors as below:

> *An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: The requested operation has failed.: Error mounting: mount exited with
>   exit code 1: helper failed with: [mntent]: warning: no final newline
>   at the end of /etc/fstab mount: only root can mount /dev/sda1 on
>   /media/ikrz/MyDrive*

I have opened fstab file as an administrator (root user), so there should be no issue with administrative authenticity.

It was working fine when I was using Linuxmint 14 **MATE**.

Please help.

I am having one more trouble which is related to user permission questioned at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984193/permission-denied-to-execute-cfx-command-from-firefox-add-on-sdk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automount it with a normal user, you have to add that flag to the fstab:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/MyDrive ntfs defaults,user 0 0
```

Also the error tells you there's no final end line in `/etc/fstab`, so open the file, get to the end of the last line, hit enter and save it.

Comment: I tried as you said, but
**An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: The requested operation has failed.: Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with: Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more information at http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged**.
Then I linked my user account with other groups like `users` and `root` using `User Management`. But did not work out.

Comment: NTFS is kinda tricky, but the link has almost all the information, just rebuild it and use setuid-root to grant permissions to your user.

Comment: Ok. I rebuild the ntfs-3g and made it setuid root. And now it is auto-mounting at start up with full read and write permission. Thank you. But it is still showing error while I remount it after unmounting once as 'only root can mount' it. So if I unmount it accidentally I have to relogin or restart my system to get mounted by root.